# Music app. How should you display free and paid purchases?

Tags: usability, user-centered-design, app

It's a free music app. The app has free and paid purchases. I wanted to give users the choice after buying to remove the purchased download but still stream the song.

**This means the states for a paid song are:**

1. Purchase button visible *User Tap button*
2. Download occurs, purchase complete
3. User can now swipe row to remove download from device.
4. Download cloud icon now visible, user can tap row or redownload the purchased song without payment

**This means the states for a free song are:**

1. Cloud icon visible
2. User can stream by tapping row or tap cloud icon to download to device

Is this the best way to handle these different types of cases?

Comment: Does the downloaded song stays in your app's directory...Why you are giving user options to remove the download from Device...Why can't he remove it from his Downloads folder......Can you illustrate your example with wireframe

Answer (score 1):

Spotify uses a system that I find quite useful: they use a little switch that simply says "available offline". In the off state the item is not downloaded to the device. In the on state the item is downloaded. This switch is available for individual tracks as well as albums and playlists so a user can download a single track, a whole album, or their own collection of tracks.